# UICollectionView SizeForItemAt Called For Every Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Let's say I have a collection view with 5000 elements each with slightly different heights. I'd like to give UICollectionView a CGSize for these cells. One optional is to conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and use `collectionView(:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`, but this is requesting the size for every cell upfront (which is causing a performance issue).

I looked into using a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`, but I would prefer to not have to deal with a ton of customer frame math. Also to do this frame math it looks like I would need to calculate the heights for all elements anyways to know what is visible when.

Is there any way to use `collectionView(:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`, but only have it ask for the cells currently visible?

Sample Code with all complexity removed:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! // This is linked from a storyboard with a single collectionView inside a single VC.
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 21
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.black, UIColor.green].randomElement()!
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        print("Size requested") // Called 2100 times :(
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 3 - 10, height: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: CollectionView is heavily optimized for reusability. sizeForItemAt will be called for cells that are going to be visible. if you are getting poor performance, then there can be a number of reasons. like it depends upon how you are calculating the size, or what kind of operations you are performing on cells. etc please post your code and may be we then able to analyse what is causing the problem

Comment: @SahilManchanda I agree that was my assumption as well, but it is asking for the size of every cell in collectionview upfront. To make sure it wasn't something in my larger implementation I tried to reproduce in a simple project. See above code.

Comment: okay, let me try this on my end

Comment: I tried this and yes it does get called 2100 times. I did some googling found a similar SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/53454555/2299040 where Grzegorz Krukowski said it's expected behavior for collectionviewFlowLayout. One possible solution to overcome this is to use paging i.e. getting a small number of data in sets

Comment: I changed the number of items to 1000 and removed numberofsections  but it didn't lag

Comment: @AlexPelletier - are you actually going to be calculating the size (different sizes?) for every cell?

Comment: In the production code the cell size is dynamic, this example was the highlight how often the function is called. Thanks for the feedback! I seems like an oversight to have this function called for every cell upfront, but oh well.

Comment: @AlexPelletier - in general... If you are using dynamically sized cells, you do so with constraints and setting `.estimatedItemSize`. If you implement `sizeForItemAt` all the cells are queried in order to determine the scrollable-size of the entire collection.